# GCovr generate a 0% coverage report, if cpp,gcno and gcda files are not present at same folder

Tags: gcovr

I have two folder inside same folder as below :-
    1.src (it contains my cpp file)
    2.linux (where I am running g++ and executing o file)
now I am running commands as below

```
cd linux
g++ --coverage ../src/example1.cpp -o example1
./example1
cd ..
/opt/gcovr-3.2//scripts/gcovr -v -r .
```

I got output as, with 0% coverage

> Scanning directory . for gcda/gcno files...
>   Found 2 files (and will process 1)
>   Running gcov: 'gcov /opt/gcovr-3.2/doc/examples/example1/linux/example1.gcda --branch-counts --branch-probabilities --preserve-paths --object-directory /opt/gcovr-3.2/doc/examples/example1/linux' in '/opt/gcovr-3.2/doc/examples/example1/linux'
>   Parsing coverage data for file /opt/gcovr-3.2/doc/examples/src/example1.cpp
>     Filtering coverage data for file /opt/gcovr-3.2/doc/examples/src/example1.cpp
>   Gathered coveraged data for 0 files

To debug further, I goto 'linux' folder as run below command

```
gcov /opt/gcovr-3.2/doc/examples/example1/linux/example1.gcno --branch-counts --branch-probabilities --preserve-paths --object-directory /opt/gcovr-3.2/doc/examples/example1/linux
```

I got output as, with valid coverage

> /opt/gcovr-3.2/doc/examples/example1/linux
>           File '../src/example1.cpp'
>           Lines executed:85.71% of 7
>           Branches executed:100.00% of 2
>           Taken at least once:50.00% of 2
>           Calls executed:100.00% of 1
>           ../src/example1.cpp:creating '..#src#example1.cpp.gcov'

Now I want to know what wrong I am doing? my project is complex, so I don't want to do copy all cpp files from respective 'src' folder to respective 'linux' folder. I tried with `--object-directory` then also same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been working with gcovr and gcov since few months now.

The only thing that's different from what I am doing is that you are not specifying the path properly in "-r" flag.

You should specify the complete path always.

It's fine even if it's not canonical but path should be complete.

And always specify an extra slash "/" or "\" for linux and windows respectively after the root directory name.
For example

```
-r "/path/to/root/directory/"
```

It seems that this extra slash is important otherwise it gives problem.
Don't know the exact problem, but I assumed it doesn't search recursively without the end slash.

Answer (score 10):

gcovr uses .gcov files for analysis.
I also faced similar issue and overcame it in 2 steps by manually generating .gcov file

1. In the folder which contains gcno files run `gcov -b -l -p -c *.gcno`
   This will generate gcov files with all details from gcno and gcda files.
2. Go to Project Root Folder and run `gcovr -g -k -r . --html --html-details -o tp.html` or any gcovr command with -g option, -g option tells gcovr to process gcov output files

Hope this solution Helps..

Comment: This worked great for me!!! -k option is critical to keep .gcov files after parsing them with gcovr.

Answer (score 1):

If applicable, turn off [ccache](https://ccache.dev/).

If ccache ever does its thing (let's say you wiped the build directory), it will happily restore the object files from cache while not restoring the `*.gcno` files, because it doesn't know about those.

Answer (score 0):

Om MacOS/Darwin with Homebrew gcc/gcovr installed, it turned out that the `gcov` used by `gcovr` was `/usr/bin/gcov` which is the Apple/clang version which is incompatible.

I don't understand why there is no `/usr/local/bin/gcov` but creating that as a link to `gcov-9` solved it for me.