# cannot find an entry for .cpp.gcov in .gcno file, skipping file

Tags: gcc, gcov, lcov

```
g++ (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04) 9.4.0
gcov (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04) 9.4.0
lcov: LCOV version 1.13
```

1. g++ -g -O0 --coverage main.cpp -o main
2. ./main
3. lcov -t "main" -o main.info -c -d . --gcov-tool gcov-9

The output:

```
Capturing coverage data from .
Found gcov version: 9.4.0
Scanning . for .gcda files ...
Found 1 data files in .
Processing main.gcda
geninfo: WARNING: /home/home/main.gcno: Overlong record at end of file!
geninfo: WARNING: cannot find an entry for main.cpp.gcov in .gcno file, skipping file!
Finished .info-file creation
```

4. genhtml -o report main.info

The output:

```
genhtml: ERROR: no valid records found in tracefile main.info
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far I haven't managed to utilize lcov. Yet I've found a solution that works for me.

1. Install `gcovr` https://github.com/gcovr/gcovr
2. Build your application with `-fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage -g -O0`
3. Link gcov to your executable/libs (`-lgcov`)
4. Create .gcov files with `gcov-9 -b -l -p -c *.gcno` command. (If you're using cmake you will need to run this command recursively through all CMakeFiles/{all subfolders}.dir/src/* directories)
5. `gcovr {rootDir} -r {sourceDir} -g -k --html --html-details -o tp.html`

rootDir - the directory you can access .gcov from.
sourceDir - sources that shall be in tp.html report

Comment: P.s. Thanks to these answers:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/43586279/13024483
https://stackoverflow.com/a/3755038/13024483
https://stackoverflow.com/a/46232989/13024483